# How is asymmetric cryptography safe if one of the keys is public?

Tags: encryption, public-key, attack, decryption

Let's suppose $A$ is sending a message $m$ to $B$ using asymmetric cryptography.

To guarantee the authenticity of a message, $A$ encrypts $m$ with $A$'s private key: $E(m, k_A) = m_A$.

Then, $A$ sends $m_A$ to $B$.

$B$ can check that $m_A$ was sent by $A$ using $A$'s public key $p_A$, by doing $D(m, p_A) = m$.

If the public key $p_A$ is, by definition, **public**, if an attacker intercepts the communication and get $m_A$, he could easily find $m$.

How is asymmetric cryptography safe under these conditions?

Comment: If $A$ is sending a message to $B$, the message would be encrypted with $B$'s public key for security and would be signed with $A$'s private key for authenticity. As you've shown, just doing one operation doesn't get you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is asymmetric cryptography safe under these conditions?

Well, you sort of outlined (but see kelalaka's corrections) how you would use asymmetric crypto to do authentication; that is, to make sure that the message was actually sent from $A$.

You ask "how does that provide privacy?".  The answer, of course, is "if that's all you do, it doesn't".

If we want to do privacy, that is, generate an encrypted message that only $B$ can read is that $A$ encrypts $m$ with $B$'s public key, that is, $E(m, p_B) = m_A$.  We then send $m_A$ to $B$.  $B$ can then take his private key and compute $D(m_A, k_B) = m$, recovering the original message.  No one else can read the message, because only $B$ knows $k_B$, and that's needed to decrypt the message.

Two notes:

- If we need to provide both authentication (only $A$ could have generated the message) and privacy (only $B$ could read the message), we do both; $A$ might generate the ciphertext $E(m, p_B) = m_A$, and then sign it with his private key $Sign( m_A, k_A ) = s_A$ and then send both $m_A$ and $s_A$.  $B$ can then verify the signature (with $A$'s public key), and then decrypt the message (with $B$'s private key).
- In practice, if we need to encrypt a long message, what we generally do is pick a random symmetric key (which is short), and use the public key encryption to encrypt the key, and then use the symmetric key to encrypt the message.  Symmetric encryption is far more efficient than public key crypto, and so this is a significant performance gain over using the public key encryption method multiple times to encrypt the message.

Comment: It might be beyond the scope of this question, but it should be noted that $A$ signing the encrypted text doesn't prove that $A$ generated the plaintext.

Comment: That was super clear and makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you misunderstood what is a signature and encryption with the public key.

A signature requires a hash then sign paradigm with the sender's private key so that any receiver can verify the signature. The RSA paper gave the first idea to digital signatures that were insecure and the [Rabin Signature released in 1979](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-212.pdf) is the first secure signature that contains the hashing of the message before signature. It is still secure against existential unforgeability under chosen-message attack (EUF-CMA).

$$ signature = \operatorname{Sign}(K_{prv}, \operatorname{Hash}(m))$$

$$ \{Ok, Fail\} \leftarrow \operatorname{Verify}(K_{pub}, signature)$$

Encrypt with the private key misconception is due to the RSA trapdoor permutation that enables both encryption and signature in the same mathematical way. However, keep in mind that that is only valid for textbook RSA.

- For encryption with RSA one should use [PKCS#1 v1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313) padding or [Optimal asymmetric encryption padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) (OAEP) padding schemes to be secure. Prefer the latter since that [has security proof](http://www-cse.ucsd.edu/users/mihir/papers/oae.pdf) and the former had many attacks.
- For signature, one should use the [Probabilistic Signature Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme)(PSS) scheme to be secure signing that also requires the hash then sign paradigm.

Also, never use the same RSA key pairs for encryption end signature. Have a different pair for each with a different modulus that doesn't share even a prime.

Comment: with $\operatorname{Hash}(m)$ you mean the encryption of the message $m$?

Comment: @Daniel no. The Hash of the message. It is part of the security of the signature scheme. Also, how do you sign large messages? Always consider the signature as a different operation then encryption.

Comment: I believe that the original RSA paper (in 1978) described signatures.

Comment: I'm a newbie at this. I'm professional programmer but beginner in cryptography. I know that a hash function is and I used to understand cryptography as a function $E(k,m)$, but asymmetric cryptography is strange. My only doubt right now is how can it be safe if there is an exposed key. I'm not paying attention to signatures, message size or trapdoor permutation (whatever that is).

Comment: @poncho refreshed my mind. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel that completely depends on the mathematical structure of the signature scheme and the key sizes. Consider the RSA trapdoor as an example. If you cannot factor the modulus you cannot find the inverse of $e$ modulo the $\varphi$ ( or solve the RSA problem).